# VOC Image tagging of online urls

Tags: image-processing, photo-tagging

I am searching an open source tool in order to annotate images. I know that there is some out there like ImgLab. However, I can only upload the images directly.
I would like to have a tool in which I can upload the urls of the images and the images are then displayed.

Does anyone know of this?

Cheers,
Andi

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because questions requesting recommendations for off-site resources are off-topic. It is also unclear what a`VOC` is or, or which `ImgLab` you refer to.

Comment: Imglab refers to https://imglab.ml/ and VOC refers Pascalvoc format which is annotation format for bounding boxes.